# Determining Upslope and Downslope from Line Features to Map Hydrologic Capture Zones

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4, slope

I am trying to map hydrologic capture zones (HCZ).  HCZ's are contributing areas upslope of any potential capture feature (i.e. road, pipeline path, railroad line), that would alter/impact the natural drainage pattern in a watershed.  A simplified example is show here (yellow area is HCZ, which lies partially in basin- the pink area):

[image]

I am having a lot of trouble coming up with a good method to map areas upslope and downslope of roads. My current methodology is based on @nagib's post:

[Upslope and downslope distance or area using ArcGIS Desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250259/upslope-and-downslope-distance-or-area-using-arcgis-desktop/250341#250341)

This method may have promise, but details in those steps are sparse, especially for the all important and complex second step- path distance allocation.   When I tried to mimic nagib's method, I didn't get a very intuitive result. Not surprising, because I am not very familiar with calculating upslope/downslope using path distance allocation.  The result looked like:

[image]

In mapping HCZs it seems to me that accurately defining upslope and downslope areas of roads is a critical first step.  Any resources or thoughts on a very accurate methodology for getting these areas right?  Using ArcMap 10.4 primarily, but have access to QGIS and Whitebox GAT.

**EDIT:**

Per @nagib's request here is a third pic showing second pic with contours (white lines):

[image: Image with Contours]

Also, here is a pic combining upslope/downslope areas, contours, pour point(orange point) at intersection of road(black line) and river(blue line), and the resulting subshed (white area) from that pour point:

[image]

Comment: What is upslope for one feature, might very well be a downslope for another one.

Comment: Can you show us the result of the first image to compare them? How big is the pixel size?

Comment: @FelixIP.  True.  Can you expand your thoughts on how this plays out for trying to mapping slopes relative to features that likely have changing slope themselves(in my case road features)? If it's possible to calculate slope along a road feature (which I assume is possible), would it not be possible to compare this feature relative to surrounding slope using elevation rasters?  Or are you suggesting this is a futile effort? Thanks!

Comment: @nagib.  Thanks!  Unfortunately, I don't have spatial data behind the first pic.  Just used to show simplest of examples.  Think my GIS Admin has previously mapped HCZs with spatial data behind them though.  Could ask him.  Pixel size is about 27x27.  Obviously, not ideal resolution. Before I spent the time creating another hydrological prepared DEM with better resolution figured I'd try this dataset.  Can also ask my GIS admin if he has more accurate data.

Comment: Do you have contour map of second picture? We can only compare two images to view what is the problem. Try to interpolate that pixel size maybe 10x10 or 5x5m and maybe you would see differences

Comment: @nagib.  See edit above.  I added contours.  Personally, they look pretty decent. Your thoughts?  I assume they'd only improve given more resolved elevation raster data in this process (I prefer to create from more accurate LiDAR rather than resample).  Fourth pic shows all elements I was thinking of using to model HCZ's.   I want to isolate entire surface (preferably automated if possible) that are upslope of linear road features.  Basically, anywhere a waterdrop falls that flows down to road and gets "captured" (then potentially flows to stream- though not necessarily if no stream exists).

Comment: Also, would you be willing to share more details about the path allocation distance method in your original post I referenced above?  I didn't add any optional parameters (ie cost raster or vertical/horizontal factors) in the associated ArcGIS tool. Only optional parameter I added was "in_vertical_raster"- as I assumed tool somehow calculated slope from it and inputted calculated slope as vertical factor.  I actually found the original paper in your original post, but details were sparse there, too.  I'm self teaching so any insight/help is appreciated.  Thanks!!

Comment: The third picture is all right. I think pixel size is a small problem. You need to try to classify a flat pixel and then see the result.

Comment: In ArcGIS, convert the road to a raster using Polyline to Raster. Using your surface model create a flow direction raster using the Spatial Analyst Hydrology tools. Use the flow direction raster and the rasterized road to generate a watershed using the Watershed tool. The resulting watershed will be all the areas that are uphill of the road. Next reclassify both the stream capture zone and the road capture zone to values of 0 and 1.  Add the two reclassifications together.  The pixels with values of 2 will be all the areas in the stream capture zone that also flow into your potential road.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @nagib.  When you say "small problem", do you mean resolution does not have substantial affect on results of the described workflow?  Also, what is a flat pixel?  Not sure what you mean by "classifying a flat pixel".  I'm assuming your comment is related to slope but do you mean generating a slope raster?  I've read that slope raster can be used either as a "in_cost_raster" or "in_vertical_raster" parameter in Path Allocation Distance tool- not  especially clear to me.

Comment: Thanks @GBG.  I believe this process is similar to using SAGA's Upslope Area module in QGIS on polyline road features that have been converted to raster.  I got unexpected results and errors in that workflow. All other cells in output slope area raster besides the original cells of the road raster were NoData.  Maybe it's because I used a filled DEM instead of a flow direction raster in SAGA module or, I had to adjust extents of input rasters to get module to work without error. I will try your suggestion in ArcMap using a flow direction raster and let you know what I get.

Comment: @GBG.  I tried your method.  First, I tried Polyline to Raster using ObjectID as "Value Field" parameter.  Then, I ran this in Watershed tool.  Results- which I'm hoping are similar to HCZs- seem to greatly underestimate area that was manually classified as HCZs.

Comment: Because I wasn't sure if you wanted ObjectID as "Value Field" (and subsquently the "Pour Point Field" parameter), I used Extract By Mask tool to get a road raster with extracted elevation data from DEM using original road vector as mask.  When I ran this raster in Watershed tool (using Elevation as opposed to ObjectID as pour point field), this seemed to get result where outputs were better matched to original HCZ data.  But not sure how that's helpful without unique ObjectIDs to isolate.  I'm going to try @WhiteboxDev idea: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/202942/97939 using lines.

Answer (score 2):

It's been over a month since any action on this, but I've gotten a fairly acceptable solution to capturing the HCZs using ArcMap 10.4.  It requires a hydrologically prepared DEM and accurate stream and road vector data.  The solution is:

1) Extract By Mask on the vector data representing your streams and roads.

2) Use Raster Calculator to square the extracted roads raster (ie expand the difference b/w stream and road rasters)

3) Mosaic to New Raster on to combine raster from Step 2 and stream raster from step 1

4) If need be, use Raster Calculator to set all 0 values to NoData on raster from step 3

5) Create a Flow Direction raster from DEM.

6) Run Watershed tool using flow direction raster and raster from Step 3 (or Step 4 if appropriate)

7) Use Reclassify on the watershed raster.  The first range is the natural drainage, while all other ranges are the HCZs.

8) Use Raster to Polygon to convert raster to vector polygons.

**Some positives:** can be automated in arcpy, only requires a Basic license with spatial analyst, relatively quick runtime versus manual delineation.

**Some negatives:** can create memory issues causing ArcMap to crash/freeze, requires accurate input DEM and stream/road data, differs (10-15% and less) from manually delineated HCZ data we have.  This difference seems to be rooted in the fact that the local natural topography (and therefore natural flow pattern) is overcome in areas next to artificially high roads.

Anyways, hope this is helpful to someone. Thanks for the creative suggestions. 
 If anyone has ideas on how to overcome the negatives listed above (or can connect me with another smart person who might have some ideas), that'd be great!