# Determining if Runoff Sinks drain to stream or drain to road?

Tags: road, watershed, runoff, stream

I've tried using the linked method to determine area that drains to stream vs drains to road. For some reason when I run the watershed tool on the the raster representing stream and road features, I get a lot of areas that have no data (drain to neither road nor stream). I'm not sure why this is happening.

[Determining Upslope and Downslope from Line Features to Map Hydrologic Capture Zones](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276963/determining-upslope-and-downslope-from-line-features-to-map-hydrologic-capture-z)

Picture: stream lines are in light blue, drains to stream in dark blue, road in white, drains to road in green.

[image: Stream Lines in light blue, roadds in white, drains to stream in dark blue, drains to road in green.]

This has the DEM as background.
[image]

This one has the Flow Direction Raster Behind.
[image]

at @Jon Filling the origional DEM then re running the watershed tool got me some more coverage as shown in this picture. New area is shown in yellow and rose.

[image]

Comment: Any experience with this issue? @jbrengel

Comment: Did you fill the pits in the DEM? It's possible that you have sinks (depressions) within your DEM that are capturing the flow of the areas of no data.

Comment: @Jon I got some additional coverage by filling the DEM, but it's still not working well for areas like hilltops that are farther away from the roads and streams. I added the new photo in the post.